# PHP + Facebook login - Access to first_name impossible

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been fighting with the Graph API for hours now.
Here is my problem:

I call Facebook API

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

Any use of  `$user_profile['name']` works. Calling the Facebook profile pic works too.

The problem comes with the other values.  `$user_profile['first_name']` doesn't work for example. Same for last_name, email, etc.

Is there any reason this might be occuring ?

FYI, I'm editing the Wordpress plugin "Nextend Facebook Connect", because it fails to store the first name, last name and email in the created Wordpress account.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: What shows when you `var_dump($user_profile);`?

Comment: array(2) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Valentin Richard" ["id"]=> string(17) "10200806007190430" }

Hmmm.. That explains why I can't call the other values. But why isn't there any other values?

Comment: $facebook is defined as following: 
`$facebook = new Facebook([
  'appId' => APPID
  'secret' => SECRET
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
 ]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refereed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile/5.0.0)

Try using

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name');
```

and then retrieve  first name as,

```
$first_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
```

Comment: Thaaaaaanks, it wooorks! I also passed email as a field.

Answer (score 0):

OK so `first_name` isn't being pulled through when you're using `$facebook->api('/me');` judging from your comment.

What you can do is

```
$name = explode(" ", $user_profile['name']);
```

Then you can do:

```
$first_name = $name[0]; 
$last_name  = $name[1];
```

Comment: I thought about that, but it doesn't work if the user's last name is composed of two words, and it doesn't solve the email problem...

Comment: Weird. In JavaScript, the data comes through like this: `FB.api('/me', function(data) {
                user = {
                    first_name : data.first_name,
                    last_name : data.last_name,
                    email : data.email,
                    link : data.link
                };` first_name, last_name and email are already included. Maybe the plugin you're using is out dated? @ValentinRichard

Comment: I think it is, that's why I'm trying to edit it. I just need to find out why Facebook doesn't pull the full object.